# CTools modal with webform unable to close

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I'm using the CTools modal with a webform, the form comes in via ajax. When a user is logged in, all works normally. If an anonymous user clicks on the link for the modal, I'm seeing the following behavior:

- CTools modal close button does not work. No js errors.
- The 2nd time the link to display the modal is clicked, the page links directly to the form page (no ajax, no modal).

For logged in users, the close button works and the button to trigger the overlay behaves properly on repeat clicks.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out - this was being caused by the ThemeKey module. The base page was one theme, and the ajax call was requesting default theme, trigging a reload of all the javascript.

The solution is to enable  'Bypass a request forgery protection in theme selection for Ajax responses.' and select the safe themes.